# Как с помощью JS выбрать конкретный Option по порядку из Select

Tags: javascript, html-select

Есть селект, который выдает доступные платежные системы:

```html
<select class="select" name="Curr" id="add_Curr">
  <option selected="" value="0">- {$_TRANS['select']} -</option>
    {foreach $currs as $cid => $c}
       <option value="{$cid}" {if $cid eq $smarty.post.Curr}selected{/if}>{$cid}</option>
    {/foreach}
 </select>
```

Есть допустим несколько кнопок, которые по идее при нажатии должны выбирать соответствующий `Option`, может быть по индексу. Как это можно реализовать с помощью **JS**? **JQuerry** подключен. В **JS** вообще ноль, поэтому заранее гигантское спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 3):

Выбирайте, можно по значению `value` выбрать, а можно по индексу :

```js
var select = document.querySelector('#s');
document.querySelector('#btn').addEventListener('click', function() {
  // по индексу (помним что нумерация с 0-ля)
  select.selectedIndex = 4;
});
document.querySelector('#btn2').addEventListener('click', function() {
  // по значению
  select.value = 3;
});
```

```html
<select id="s">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
</select>

<input type="button" id="btn" value="1" />
<input type="button" id="btn2" value="2" />
```